# Field automorphisms of projective spaces without the axiom of choice

Tags: projective-geometry, axiom-of-choice, group-actions, vector-spaces, automorphisms

Suppose **P** is a projective space over the field $k$. If **P** has finite dimension $n$, we can fix a base. Relative to this base, the full automorphism group of **P** can be described by the action on the points, as follows:
\begin{equation}
x \mapsto Ax^\sigma,
\end{equation}
where a point $x$ is expressed through homogeneous coordinates as a colomn vector, $A$ is an element in $\mathrm{PGL}_{n + 1}(k)$, and $\sigma$ is an automorphism of $k$ (acting on each entry of $x$).

Now if we do not accept the axiom of choice, and drop the finiteness condition on the dimension if the dimension exists at all, we know weird things can happen.

It would be consistent to say that there exist **P** without a base, and also **P** with bases of different cardinalities.

Is there still a way to define an action of an automorphism $\sigma$ on the points in these cases ?

Since the action appears to be dependent on the choice of base, I guess this means that if we work relative to, say, different bases with different cardinalities, then $\sigma$ in general will send a point to different points in the different bases.

But what happens if we have *no* base whatsoever ?

Can an action of $\sigma$ still be defined ?

Comment: I think you mean "basis", not "base". The plural of "base" is "bases", and the plural of "basis" is "bases", but it is pronounced differently: bay-siz in the first case, bay-seez in the second, with the second being the relevant one to linear algebra.